# JSON schema generation with Jackson goes into infinite loop

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

It might be that I'm missing an obvious annotation in Jackson but I have following class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonschema.JsonSchema;

@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Loop {

  private String name;
  private Loop otherLoop;

  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
  public Loop getOtherLoop() { return otherLoop; }
  public void setOtherLoop(Loop otherLoop) { this.otherLoop = otherLoop; }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Loop parent = new Loop();
    parent.setName("parent");

    Loop child = new Loop();
    child.setName("child");
    child.setOtherLoop(parent);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(child));

    JsonSchema jsonSchema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(Loop.class);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonSchema));
  }
}
```

and when I run it using Jackson 2 it goes into an infinite loop

```
{"name":"child","otherLoop":{"name":"parent"}}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.isEnabled(MapperConfig.java:106)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.getAnnotationIntrospector(SerializationConfig.java:382)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.getAnnotationIntrospector(SerializerProvider.java:307)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.createContextual(BeanSerializerBase.java:318)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._handleContextual(SerializerProvider.java:971)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:447)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.getSchema(BeanSerializerBase.java:619)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.getSchema(BeanSerializerBase.java:621)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.getSchema(BeanSerializerBase.java:621)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.getSchema(BeanSerializerBase.java:621)
```

Any ideas, workarounds?!

Comment: you have a Loop object inside the Loop class, so it goes into infinite loop. if you add @JSONIgnore, it wont go into infinite loop but that may not be the solution you need. Hmmm.

Comment: consider using an interface, like public class Loop implements AInterface and you can have private AInterface otherLoop; in the Loop class.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, it might be better to just open a bug report at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues

Comment: Reported as an issue and will be fixed in a reworked Jackson implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Loop {
   @XMLAttribute(name = "Name")
   private String name;
   @XMLAttribute(name = "Loops")
   private List<Loop> listLoop;

   //getters and setters    
}
```

Comment: That does not really help because an empty interface is not what is expected in that place. It really is a Loop object. But as soon as you add 'AInterface getOtherLoop()' in interface it stops working with the same stackoverflow.

Comment: if you add the same class object in the class, you're creating infinite loop, why would you need a same class object in the same class? I don't understand. You could create a new class for that purpose.

Comment: LinkedList is a classic example. Trees too. Relations with objects of same type are common: spouse, children... and abstractions that like component composite pattern. Even the more generic case of A links to B and B links to A the json schema generation will fail. And adding more levels in a transitive way A -> B -> C -> A all fail.

Comment: I agree. updated my answer. using an interface as i suggested earlier wont help your case like you pointed it out. Instead you could have a list of objetcs which jackson can understand and wont go into infinite loop.

Comment: When I run this with private fields it gives me nothing: {"type":"object","properties":{}}. Making these public I still get a stackoverflow.

Comment: don't make them public, add xmlattribute for fields. (answer updated)